# Transform my icon SVGs to 32px x 32px icons in Inkscape

Tags: icon, inkscape, svg

I'm a newbie to designing things in Inkscape.
I'm developing a website, in which the tabbed content will have icons.

Some of the icons I designed, I see, aren't uniformly `32px x 32px`, when I set the X-axis width to `32px`. I want all my icons to be `32px x 32px`, because all the sites I've been studying, use `32px x 32px` and the benefit I see in that is uniformity, and that it's a W3C standard or something.

Anyways, here's my icon:

[image: search tab icon]

How can I resize it to `32px x 32px` without the malforming weirdness?
TBH, I tried setting the dimensions manually without preserving the original aspect ratio, but still the thing wouldn't be `32px x 32px` exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Rotate the icon clockwise until the stem of the magnifying glass is at a 45 degree angle. That will give it more of a square composition to begin with, and then you'll be able to scale it with without distorting anything.

Comment: That's alright, but what about other such icons? I have a mail envelope icon that's kinda rectangular.